# Python3, Gtk3, adjustment value randomly changing

Tags: python, gtk

Given the following python code, it should create a GtkAdjustment with a value of 123.

It is (apparently randomly) getting different values. Either the value `123.0` the min value `1.0` or `0.0` (Constant, not the parameter).

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from gi.repository import Gtk

adjustment = Gtk.Adjustment(123,1,200,1,10,0)
print(str(adjustment.get_value()))
```

What is going on?

**Edit:** The following C program acts as expected, so it's specific to python:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

  GtkAdjustment * adjustment = gtk_adjustment_new(123.0,1.0,200.0,1.0,10.0,0.0);
  printf("%f\n", gtk_adjustment_get_value(adjustment));

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the generic constructor. In C terms, it is first constructing the object with `g_object_new` and then setting the values one by one. Apparently that does not happen in a deterministic order.

The better approach is to use keyword arguments to fix the values to names

```
adjustment = Gtk.Adjustment(value=123, lower=1, upper=200, ...)
```

or use the actual constructor function that has a fixed order of arguments

```
adjustment = Gtk.Adjustment.new(123, 1, 200, 1, 10, 0)
```

Comment: I thought the generic constructor *was* mapped to the real constructor. TIL. Which would you choose?

Comment: Disregarding this particular problem, I am always in favor of keyword arguments because they document what's going on.

Comment: Are there no specific problems arising from assigning values one by one instead of using the proper constructor?

Comment: No, why? I mean it's not any different as if I would create an "empty" adjustment and set the values manually. In fact, the new constructor is doing effectively [the same](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtkadjustment.c#n397).

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing forgetting something, or does `g_object_new` already handle any initialization issues I'm thinking of?

Comment: `g_object_new` creates an object from a given type and goes through the list of constructor arguments and sets them before the construction of the object is finished. It cannot know the semantics of the actual object, thus does not handle initialization issues, that's up to the developer of the widget/object. In case of the adjustment it's impossible `g_object_new` cannot know that value should be set after the limits.